# sporadic 403 (Forbidden) errors with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a process that will download files from S3, make changes to the files, and then upload the updated file back to S3. This works fine 99+% of the time. However, it seems that there are transient issues with S3 that cause this to fail for short periods of time, generating 403 (Forbidden) responses.

For example, log entries from one such incident the other day

```
2018-05-02 19:01:19 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 19:01:20 INFO  Uploaded file
2018-05-02 19:01:20 INFO  Updated key (renamed file)

2018-05-02 19:27:26 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 19:27:26 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 19:27:26 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 19:27:26 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 19:27:27 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 19:27:27 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 19:27:27 INFO  Uploaded file
2018-05-02 19:27:28 ERROR Failed to upload file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 19:27:28 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 19:27:28 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )

2018-05-02 20:30:32 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 20:30:32 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 20:30:32 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 20:30:32 ERROR Failed to download file, cause: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; )
2018-05-02 20:30:32 INFO  Downloaded file
2018-05-02 20:30:33 INFO  Uploaded file
```

These entries were all from the same file.  It was successfully download, modified and uploaded again.  30 minutes later, it took 4 attempts to download it, then the upload failed.  3 minutes after that, it took 3 attempts to download, then it was successfully uploaded.

We are using the AWS Java SDK client for this.  Has anyone had a similar experience and figured out how to resolve?  Is it considered normal for S3 calls to fail occasionally even though the requests are valid?

Comment: Are there additional details or a message in the AmazonS3Exception? Are these temporary credentials (from an IAM role or STS) or are they permanent (e.g. IAM user)? Is the client clock synced?

Comment: We aren't logging any additional details from the S3 exception except the request id and extended request id.  These are temporary credentials (STS).  Yes, the clocks are synced.

Comment: I would start by logging all the information possible from the exception: ex.getAdditionalDetails(), ex.getErrorResponseXml() and ex.getMessage(). If that doesn't explain the problem then I would consider raising a support issue with AWS and supplying the request IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with other cloud object providers, not with S3.

The solution taken was to handle the `403` response (log it to find any kind of pattern or concrete file object) and redo the request up to a maximum number of times.

Generally, upon the first `403` response, the second request was done, and received the `200 Ok`.

In our case, problems were solved after the provider did updates in few of the problematic nodes It was a matter of updates. This can give you a clue, in order to workaround the inconsistency:

1. Try to create a different bucket. It might be a concrete bucket configuration bug in aws side. Move your files there. Keep it under observation and check if the `403` cases got reduced or even disappear.
2. Create a different bucket in another region (the closest maybe) it can give you better clues about possible networking issues.
3. Use a different object storage. If the issue still arise, then the most probable is that any of the modules you use is inconsistent with the current version/protocol of S3. Make sure you update to the last version any S3 or aws wrapper library you use in your project.